Docker and Postgresql with mounted (local): chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata': Permission denied
I am using the following standard to mount a local volume into my postgres container as described here: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres
$ docker run -d \
    --name some-postgres \
    -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword \
    -e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata \
    -v /custom/mount:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
    postgres

It worked well for months but since the last docker update to Docker version 27.3.1, build ce1223035a it does not work anymore. I'm using colima on my Mac with the docker engine.
When I run the same command now I get the following error message:
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata': Permission denied
Why the heck did it work before and now causes issues? As far as I understand the documentation as longs as you keep the standard as mentioned here --> https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/361#issuecomment-490241136
everything should be alright.
Any ideas?

The obvious question is what the ownership/permissions are on /custom/mount and on /custom/mount/pgdata. Also whether this is mounted from the Mac itself or from the linux VM that docker desktop installs.

So here is an update --> I have a Mac with macOS 15.0 and colima + docker v27.3.1. Another Mac with macOS 14.7 + Docker Desktop including docker v27.2.0.
On the newer Mac the following command does not work But on the older one:
docker run -d --name timotest -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata -v /Users/timo/postgres/timotest:/var/lib/postgresql/data -p 5432:5432 postgres:latest

On the newer system I even installed an older version of docker and that didn't help as well. Could it be a change in macOS?

Another update. I uninstalled colima and the docker formulae and installed docker desktop on the macOS15 machine as well. Works as expected. I think I'll open an issue on the colima project.

I've first seen your comment at docker-library/postgres#361. After further research, I've found a solution in Colima repo, here.
Here is the solution:
# delete existing instance
colima delete 

# create a new instance with 'vz' instead of the default 'qemu'
# vz is macOS Virtualization.Framework
colima start --vm-type=vz

You can also enable Rosetta 2 emulation for better performance in amd64 emulation:
colima start --vm-type=vz --vz-rosetta

Alternatively, you can use colima template with the following options to set the default options, to avoid having to pass them to colima start:
- vmType: qemu
+ vmType: vz

...

- rosetta: false
+ rosetta: true

...

# needed when using `colima start --edit`
# but, you can still set it for good measure even if not using --edit
- mountType: sshfs
+ mountType: virtiofs


@Yusuf thank you very much that you posted the solution here on stackoverflow as well! I would like to thank you here as well for posting the solution. Changing the vm-type in colima to vz did the trick.
Thank you very much!
